# Playframework 2 and Netty Development

Tags: playframework-2.0, netty

Im using playframework 2 for web, but now I also need to add some custom functionality to netty, add flash sockets, flash policy file and maybe later on some streaming.  All the netty code can be found on the web, thats not my issue. I just would like to know how to integrate playframework with netty, whats the best way to add these features in playframework 2 to netty.

For example, if I write a custom playframework 2 module, where would i put the netty code?  Or i have a playframework web app, where do I put the netty code, how do I organize the app.

Im no unprofessional, so the more simple the explanation the better, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old, but for the next guy coming here :

Short answer : 
- play2 framework has a FlashPolicyHandler class, and it should do the job out of the box. 
- But if you want exchange message between flash and netty, you need more, and you could take a look at [netty game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) wich do the job. But it require a bit skills to understand exactly how it work. By the way it handle a way of communicating between as3 and netty. That's a custom way and I'm not sure you could use the build-in flex method (flex is a gui as3 framework).

Now, you talk about netty and play... let's explain who is who...

Netty is "just" a framework to handle NIO non blocking IO. With netty you could make any server wich listen to a socket and get data back to client, in any protocol TCP/UDP http SMTP etc etc... For exemple google netty+smtp or netty+UDP ..+loadbalancer etc etc.

What have done play guys ? They have build play "under" netty without modification of netty. The best way to understand is to take an earlier version of play and take a look at the entry point class witch is in package : play.server.Server. look arround in this package and you'll learn a lot. You'll see that they create 2 services on for http other for https. And if you look at HttpServerPipelineFactory class, you'll discover that flashPolicy is first things they handle.

I'm not a power user of play framework, so I don't know how to implement modules. But in fact you could add a new service in the server class, you'll need a new ChannelPipeline, a new boostrap etc.

here a sample of what I have done for amf3

```
package org.domorobo.scale.server.amf3;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.domorobo.scale.server.api.IServer;
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class AMF3Server  implements IServer{
    private static final Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AMF3Server.class);
    public void start() {
        l.info("server start");
        // Configure the server.
        NioServerSocketChannelFactory factory = null;
        factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),             Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        ServerBootstrap serverBosstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
        // Set up the event pipeline factory.
        try {
            serverBosstrap.setPipelineFactory(new Amf3PipelineFactory());
            serverBosstrap.setOption("child.tcpNodelay", true);
            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            serverBosstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8089));
            if (l.isInfoEnabled() == true) {
                l.info("server started listenning at 8089 port");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            l.error("OHO\r\n", e);
        }
}
```

What you could found in Amf3PipelineFactory class is a list of frameDecoder you could implement for your own protocol.

What we use to do is to not directly modify a framework so I don't recommand you to modify play framework. You should ask them where to put a new service and new pipeline.